# Switching View through a function

Tags: iphone, ipad, webview, view, switch-statement

I'm working on an iPhone/iPad application and trying to switch views through a function call, not by a button. I've seen lots of sources switching views triggered by a button, but there's nothing that explains how to switch views triggered by a function. I tried to do this on my own, but it failed. Here's the code that I tried:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     if (self.webview == nil) {
         self.webview = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
         /* webview initialized with storyboard */
         if (self.view.superview == nil) {
             [self.view insertSubview:self.webview.view atIndex:0];
         }
         [storyboard release];
     }
 }
```

This is viewDidLoad of the viewController.m. First, it shows WebView.

```
- (void)changeView {
     self.normview = [[AlternateViewController alloc] init];
     /* normview initialized with storyboard */

     [UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:nil];
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
     [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

     [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:YES];
     [self.webview viewWillDisappear:YES];
     [self.webview viewDidDisappear:YES];
     [self.webview.view removeFromSuperview];
     [self.view insertSubview:self.normview.view atIndex:0];
     [self.normview viewWillAppear:YES];
     [self.normview viewDidAppear:YES];

     [UIView commitAnimations];
 }
```

And when this changeView function (in a viewController.m) is called, It should change the view from webview to normview (actually, it works fine when the same code is triggered by a button). But when I call this function in other file (not viewController.m), such as

```
ViewController *viewcontroller = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[viewcontroller changeView];
```

It doesn't work. Anyone can give a clue to solve this or an alternative way? (ps. I'm testing on iPad.)

Answer (score 0):

You can switch views with this function:

```
YourView *screen = [[YourView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];
    [screen release];
```

You can set the modaltransitionstyle to your willings.

Don't forget to import your headerfile at the top of your class.

```
#import "YourView.h"
```

Comment: Thanks for comment, but of course I already knew that. I couldn't use it, however, because what actually I wanted to do was presenting imagepicker on webview(as you explained, but imagepicker instead of screen), but if it's triggered by outer function(not by a button), it didn't work. That's why I tried to switch views, where normview present imagepicker when its viewDidAppear triggered. If I can make presentModalViewController:animated to work when it's called by other file (not view controller.m), I don't even need to switch view. Can you give me a solution?